# How to call dll file (Written in c#) in Visual Studio on Mac for IOS?

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am new in IOS development using Visual Studio on mac, i don't know how to add .dll file in visual studio project and also how to set path of that external dll file which is located on my desktop. I imported the file something like this but found FileNotFoundException.
[image: I found this exception]

Comment: right click on References in your solution explorer and select "Add"

Comment: why do you want to add the dll file ?It seem is been created  by  system

Comment: Actually i am using third party library to calculate the planets values, so i found two dll files , one i added in the References folder while the other one not being added . So i am trying to provide path of this external file , but i did not worked. Please help me.

Comment: Have you try what I did said?

Comment: I have two dll files one of which i copied inside the References folder it works fine but another one not being copied perhaps it is static lib.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the file swedll.32.dll not been found. Swedll32.dll is a type of dll file associated with Third-Party Software developed by Astrograph Software for the Windows Operating System. 
 I suggest that you can scan your PC for swedll32.dll registry errors.